# AngularJS: mdDatepicker is one day-off

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, timezone, angularjs-material

I'm using Angularjs Material [datepicker](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) extension

Here is a simple usage example:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="$ctrl.date"></md-datepicker>
```

And in my app config:

```
$mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
  if (!date) {
    return '';
  }
  return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
};
```

And here is a problem I facing - when a date was selected via calendar it returns correct value, 
but when I type an exact date e.g. 
`2012-12-12`
 it gives me a one day off value
`Tue Dec 11 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

P.S. Here is a [Codeopen](https://codepen.io/luninroman/pen/gzaPvR) I found with such a problem

Answer (score 1):

It is a know bug in javascript 
example:
`new Date ('2012/03/21');` --> `Wed Mar 21 2012 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

`new Date ('2012-03-21');` --> `Tue Mar 20 2012 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

the best advice i could give you is changing `-` to `/`

Try this instead

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <md-content>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-change="change(myDate)"></md-datepicker>
  </md-content>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.myDate = new Date();

      $scope.minDate = new Date(
        $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
        $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
        $scope.myDate.getDate());

      $scope.maxDate = new Date(
        $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
        $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
        $scope.myDate.getDate()); 
console.log($scope.myDate.toLocaleDateString(), $scope.myDate.toUTCString());

       $scope.change = function(data) { 
        console.log($scope.myDate.toLocaleDateString());
        console.log( $scope.myDate.toUTCString());     
      }

})


.config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
  $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
    return moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
  };
});
```

Comment: It still gives me one day off value

Comment: What is your current timezone?

Comment: Eastern timezone

Comment: Hi @LuninRoman i think it's really a known issue, please refer here https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4636

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I already read the whole topic and did not find anything that can help me out

Comment: Hi @LuninRoman i think the best advice i could give you is changing `-`  to `/`

Comment: I updated my answer, here a link for example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZobQXV?editors=1111

Comment: I will consider your suggestion, but my customer request `-` styled format, thank you!